# OCaml writing a timeout function using Async

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, functional-programming, ocaml, ocaml-lwt

I'm trying to write a function that tries to evaluate a function, but stops after a specific timeout.

I tried to use `Deferred.any`, which returns a deferred that is fulfilled when one of the underlying deferred is fulfilled.

```
type 'a output = OK of 'a | Exn of exn

let fun_test msg f eq (inp,ans) =
   let outp = wait_for (Deferred.any
     [ return (try OK (f inp) with e -> Exn e)
     ; (after (Core.Std.sec 0.0) >>| (fun () -> Exn TIMEOUT))])
   in {msg = msg;inp = inp;outp = outp;ans = ans;pass = eq outp ans}
```

I was not sure how to extract a value from the deferred monad, so I wrote a function 'wait_for' which just spins until the underlying value is determined.

```
let rec wait_for x =
   match Deferred.peek x with
      | None -> wait_for x
      | Some done -> done;;
```

This did not work. After reading through the [Async chapter of Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/concurrent-programming-with-async.html), I realized I needed to start the scheduler. However I'm not sure where I would call `Schedule.go` in my code. I do not see where the type `go : ?raise_unhandled_exn:bool -> unit -> Core.Std.never_returns` would fit into code where you actually want your asynchronous code to return. The documentation for `go` says "Async programs do not exit until `shutdown` is called."

I was beginning to doubt I had taken the entirely wrong approach to the problem until I found a very similar solution to that same problem on [this Cornell website](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2014sp/lectures/18/more-async.html)

```
let timeout (thunk:unit -> 'a Deferred.t) (n:float) : ('a option) Deferred.t
  = Deferred.any 
    [ after (sec n) >>| (fun () -> None) ; 
      thunk () >>= (fun x -> Some x) ]
```

Anyway, I'm not quite sure my use of `wait_for` is correct. Is there a canonical way to extract a value from the deferred monad? Also how do I start the scheduler?

Update:
I tried writing a timeout function using only `Core.Std.Thread` and `Core.Std.Mutex`.

```
  let rec wait_for lck ptr =
    Core.Std.Thread.delay 0.25;
    Core.Std.Mutex.lock lck;
    (match !ptr with
     | None -> Core.Std.Mutex.unlock lck; wait_for lck ptr
     | Some x -> Core.Std.Mutex.unlock lck; x);;

  let timeout t f =
    let lck = Core.Std.Mutex.create () in
    let ptr = ref None in
    let _ = Core.Std.Thread.create
      (fun () -> Core.Std.Thread.delay t;
                 Core.Std.Mutex.lock lck;
                 (match !ptr with
                  | None -> ptr := Some (Exn TIMEOUT)
                  | Some _ -> ());
                 Core.Std.Mutex.unlock lck;) () in
    let _ = Core.Std.Thread.create
      (fun () -> let x = f () in
                 Core.Std.Mutex.lock lck;
                 (match !ptr with
                  | None -> ptr := Some x
                  | Some _ -> ());
                 Core.Std.Mutex.unlock lck;) () in
    wait_for lck ptr
```

I think this is pretty close to working. It works on computations like `let rec loop x = print_string ".\n"; loop x`, but it does not work on computations like `let rec loop x = loop x`. I believe the problem right now is that if the computation `f ()` loops infinitely, then its thread is never preempted, so none of other threads can notice the timeout has expired. If the thread does IO like printing a string, then the thread does get preempted. Also I don't know how to kill a thread, I couldn't find such a function in the [documentation for Core.Std.Thread](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core/#Core_thread)

Comment: may be some hints (and may be you already read it):  https://github.com/janestreet/async/blob/master/example/timeouts.ml.

Comment: I became rather frustrated with `async` and switched to `lwt`. I didn't find anything in that code. As far as I can tell `Command.async` expects a function which returns a `unit Deferred.t` and `Command.run` returns `()`. I was looking for a function that lets me run an asynchronous computation and blocks until it returns the result.

Comment: ... I have tried timeout.ml, and surprisingly I cannot see any timeout when executing it...

Comment: Related: https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/concurrent-programming-with-async.html#working-with-system-threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I came up with is

```
let kill pid sign = 
  try Unix.kill pid sign with
  | Unix.Unix_error (e,f,p) -> debug_print ((Unix.error_message e)^"|"^f^"|"^p)
  | e -> raise e;;


let timeout f arg time default = 
  let pipe_r,pipe_w = Unix.pipe () in
  (match Unix.fork () with
   | 0 -> let x = Some (f arg) in
          let oc = Unix.out_channel_of_descr pipe_w in
          Marshal.to_channel oc x [];
          close_out oc;
          exit 0
   | pid0 -> 
      (match Unix.fork () with
       | 0 -> Unix.sleep time;
              kill pid0 Sys.sigkill;
              let oc = Unix.out_channel_of_descr pipe_w in
              Marshal.to_channel oc default [];
              close_out oc;
              exit 0
       | pid1 -> let ic = Unix.in_channel_of_descr pipe_r in
                 let result = (Marshal.from_channel ic : 'b option) in
                 result ));;
```

I think I might be creating two zombie processes with this though. But it is the only solution that works on `let rec loop x = loop x` when compiled using `ocamlopt` (The solution using `Unix.alarm` given [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora168.html) works when compiled with `ocamlc` but not when compiled with `ocamlopt`).